# How to prevent Restkit RKObjectMapping keyPath being serialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20, rkobjectmapping

I want to map the following parameter and POST this request body to the server.

```
RKObjectMapping * mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MessagingRequestModel class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"sessionId": @"sessionId",
                                              @"dateFrom": @"dateFrom",
                                              @"dateTo": @"dateTo",
                                              @"MessageVO.seqId": @"seqId"
                                              }];
```

The server expecting me to have keypath like `MessageVO.seqId` but Restkit had serializing my keyPath to something like `MessageVO[seqId]`, which server can't recognise this keypath.

I have tried something like `manager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;` but server do not recongnise JSON type as POST body.

How can I prevent keyPath `.seqId` being converted to `[seqId]` in RestKit RKObjectMapping?